# Failed to load all resources - error 500

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem where i get this error in the developer console, for all css, image and js files:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

The file name and path looks fine and it's happening for ALL resources. The project is an ASP.NET MVC project, which my co-worker can build and run just fine, without these errors. The project is located in my usual projects folder and i have never experienced this problem before. I also checked the folder permissions, and i am completely clueless as to why this is happening.

The resources are bundled, but if i create the links to the resources manually, it throws the same errors in the developer console.

Have anyone ever tried something like this before?

Log: [Log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B980X7wHCv_bRE9UVnhwbmVVM1E)

Tracelog: [Tracelog](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B980X7wHCv_bYXRBb2lfMHlKcTA/view?usp=sharing)

BundleConfig.cs

```
public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.simplemodal.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.flot.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.flot.categories.min.js"
                        ));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/language").Include(
                "~/Language/english.js",
                "~/Language/spanish.js",
                "~/Language/french.js"
               ));


            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                "~/Styles/StyleNuheat.css",
                "~/Styles/buttons.css",
                "~/Styles/energy.css",
                "~/Styles/modalwindow.css",
                "~/Styles/dropdown.css",
                "~/Styles/jquery-ui.css"
                ));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/thermostat").Include(
                "~/Scripts/appl_thermostats.js",
                "~/Scripts/appl_thermostat_details.js",
                "~/Scripts/appl_schedule.js"
                ));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/general").Include(
                "~/Scripts/appl_supporter.js",
                "~/Scripts/appl_master.js",
                "~/Scripts/appl_navigation.js",
                 "~/Scripts/appl_general.js"
                ));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/energy").Include(
                "~/Scripts/appl_energy.js", 
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"

                ));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/useraccount").Include(
                "~/Scripts/appl_useraccount.js"
                ));
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/groups").Include(
                "~/Scripts/appl_groups.js"
                ));
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/login").Include(
                "~/Scripts/appl_login.js"
                ));


        }
    }
```

Comment: The linked question has nothing to do with my problem at all. He is trying to make an Ajax call and in my case, the server doesn't load any resource files at all..

Comment: I'm afraid there is not enough information to help here. Assuming you are running IIS or IIS Express, try to enable Failed Request Tracing to see what's going on on the server - https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/tracing/tracefailedrequests

Comment: I agree, but i didn't know what else to provide really. I'll look into it. thanks

Comment: @SergeyRybalkin It would seem that Failed Request Tracing was already enabled, but i can conclude nothing from it, im afraid...

Comment: Can you show your bundle configs?

Comment: I have added it to the question

Comment: @Thomas, you've attached the wrong trace log - this one is for request to http://localhost:51152/ which returned 200 OK. Please attach tracelog for request that returned code 500

Comment: @SergeyRybalkin I have changed the link to another tracelog with error code 500

Comment: @ThomasTeilmann, your Google drive link says "You need permission"

Comment: @SergeyRybalkin Sorry! i went on my lunch break, ill fix it ASAP

Comment: @SergeyRybalkin Did that help?

Comment: @ThomasTeilmann yes, thanks. I've posted an answer below

Comment: Not that it's entirely relevant to your question, but use `~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js` or `~/Scripts/jquery.min.js` in your bundle, not both. If you're using the jQuery NuGet package, use the former. Otherwise, you're eventually going to experience jQuery load errors, as you'll wind up loading jQuery twice if there is both a `jquery-2.whatever.min.js` and a `jquery.min.js` file in your scripts directory..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to the TraceLog file that you provided you have a problem in your web.config file. An exception message is `C:\Users\teilmann\source\Nuheat\oj.web\oj.web.main\web.config ( 112) :Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type "mimeMap" with unique key attribute "fileExtension" set to ".json"`

Most likely you have a MIME type defined for JSON files both on the WebSite and application level

Comment: I located the mimeMap .json in the projects web config, and commented it out. That worked! I have no idea why my co-worker have no problems running it.. Thanks!

Comment: Probably he doesn't have this defined on the WebSite level. You two should agree on where to define JSON MIME type, otherwise one of you will always have a problem with this.

Comment: For me the issue was a woff2 mimeMap being setup in the web config file (which 2013 needed and apparently 2015 doesn't)

Comment: My issue was with the mimeMap put in from TypeScript!  I removed this: ' <mimeMap fileExtension=".ts" mimeType="application/x-typescript"/>' From my Web.config and now the icons show!

Comment: @Airborne But why would you want to serve *.ts files to the browser? Shouldn't you compile them to JavaScript first?

Comment: @SergeyRybalkin Yes, all I am saying at some point in time that line got added without my knowledge to the config file.

Comment: In my case it was also this entry I needed in VS 2013. 
<mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/otf" />. After Moving to VS 2015 I had to delete it from the web.config.

Comment: Never found the real error in my logs, but re-creating web.config solved my problem

Answer (score 5):

I am working on Win2012 server and using IIS 8.5 .

Please check "staticcontent" section in web config.
There is a line in our config for mimemap and mimetype .

*mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff"*

I commented this line and it started working. 500 error got resolved for me.

Comment: I have the similar problem. I remarked then it worked. Then I unremarked back and it still worked.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it's beacuse of permission, Make sure that your folder has a right permission for `IIS_IUSRS` account.

Comment: Do you have any idea why this could suddenly be a problem, and for this project only? I have all my projects in this folder.. Also adding permissions for this account didn't help much, im afraid. thanks though

Comment: @ThomasTeilmann Actually It sounds like a permissions error, By the way, you can also check your bundle configuration. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423253/mvc-bundling-failed-to-load-resource

Comment: It's added to the question

Comment: Please just remember, that this project build and run just fine on several co-workers computers, so it shouldn't really be an issue with the bundle config

Comment: How do i then grant the right permissions for that account?

Comment: Follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388698/mvc-i-have-deployed-my-application-but-css-only-works-when-i-log-in?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by removing the content of the staticContent in my web.config. IIS 10 was complaining about having duplicate fileExtentions keys in web.cofing.

Answer (score 0):

If the css is not loaded, use the developer tool in the Chrome to see the css name. Navigate to that css in the browser- If the custom error mode is turned off, it will show the actual error. 
In my case, duplicate mimetype was present.