# Every resource results in: Failed to load resources with service code 500

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis

I have a new windows 10 machine trying to run an mvc application through visual studio but the page only partially loads. When looking at the F12 developer console in chrome I see that all the css and script files called in the layout page are all resulting in a "Failed to load resources with service code 500"

This application runs perfectly fine on multiple other machines, just not on the new one. The status code 500 leads me to believe there must be some sort of problem with the iis express visual studio runs the application in, or some other configuration with in visual studio itself.

Comment: Can you give some more details like what authentication method your are using, Whats app pool identity? Are there any additional http modules being used etc? To me it looks like NTFS permission issue where app pool's identity doesn't have read permission on folder where scripts and styles are stored.

Comment: The authentication method in the iis express config file shows anonymous authentication enabled and windows auth disabled

Comment: Also, the app pool being used is the "Clr4IntegratedAppPool" created by iis express

Comment: I've just managed to confirm with my machine at work...all the app pool settings/bindings/folder permissions are all exactly the same between the two machines

Answer (score 0):

OK managed to come across another topic with the exact problem:

[Failed to load all resources - error 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475659/failed-to-load-all-resources-error-500)

In my case I checked through the log files and found there was a duplicate MIME type defined for .less files.

This has been defined in my web.config file as this wasn't automatically defined in the IIS Express applicationhost.config on all the other machines, but for my new machine, this has been automatically defined and so there was a duplicate entry. I have removed this from the iis config and works fine now.